# Do sub-addresses and disposable addresses have their own private viewkeys and spendkeys?

Tags: viewkey, spend-key, disposable-address, sub-address

I was just wondering since disposable addresses and sub-addresses are derived from the main wallet address.

Comment: "Also would having the private viewkey or spendkey of the main address affect the security of all the disposable addresses and sub-addresses?" This part is unclear to me. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I will just remove that part of the question since those addresses have no keys to get affected by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Given an output pubkey `P` in a new transaction with its tx pubkey being `R`, you can recognize it as your incoming transfer by using your private viewkey `a`, looking for `P - Hs(a*R)*G` in your hashtable and finding an entry recoding the sub-address's index `j`. Its private key `P=x*G` is obtained as `x = Hs(a*R) + b + Hs(a || j)`. So you need both of the original private view and spend keys for receiving funds transferred to sub-addresses and disposable addresses.